# How to temporarily filter out all files that don’t end by .sh in Visual Studio Code’s explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to temporarily filter out all files that don’t end by `.sh` in Visual Studio Code’s explorer.

Is that possible? Trying to find an easy way to audit all shell scripts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a more permanent solution:

```
"files.exclude": {
  "**/node_modules": true,
    "**/*.[^s]*": true,
    "**/*.s[^h]*": true,
},
```

setting seems to work.  You will still get folders but the only files will be `.sh` extensions.

---

Alternatively, you can filter the Explorer files by, when focus is in the Explorer, typing `.sh`.  When you are done, hover over the little highlighted `.sh` in the upper right corner of the Explorer view and select `Clear` to return to normal.

You will get only `.sh*` files this way, so if you extensions of `.sh2` or a filename like `abcd.shabc.txt` they would also appear but I assume this will get you where you want to go.

with `Workbench > List: Keyboard Navigation` set to `filter`.

Comment: Thanks Mark... I was hoping for a temporary alternative that doesn't involve settings (which requires many steps to turn on and off. That said, thanks for sharing. I guess this is the only way?

Comment: Ah, see edit above to filter the Explorer contents.